# Showing image in popup using a library

Tags: android, android-studio, popup

I am trying to show the image in a popup window using this library

> implementation 'com.github.chathuralakmal:AndroidImagePopup:1.2.1'

everything is working good but the popup still blank with no image

I think the problem is that I am using glide to download the image from URL and show it in the image view :

this my code :

```
Glide.with(this).load(cleaned_image).apply(requestOptions).into(cleaned_img);



        final ImagePopup imagePopup = new ImagePopup(this);

        imagePopup.setWindowHeight(800); // Optional
        imagePopup.setWindowWidth(800); // Optional
        imagePopup.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  // Optional
        imagePopup.setFullScreen(true); // Optional
        //imagePopup.setHideCloseIcon(true);  // Optional
        imagePopup.setImageOnClickClose(true);  // Optional

        imagePopup.initiatePopup(cleaned_img.getDrawable());

        cleaned_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                imagePopup.viewPopup();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this version of Glide

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'//for kotlin
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just added drawable id not drawable and it works for me.Like this

```
imagePopup.initiatePopup(context.getResources().getDrawable(image_list.get(position)));
```

where image list is the arraylist of drawable id

Answer (score 0):

If you use Glide, just try the solution the author of the popup library (https://github.com/chathuralakmal/AndroidImagePopup) suggests for Glide:

```
imagePopup.initiatePopupWithGlide(cleaned_image);
```

Comment: I tried to use this but, there is something wrong he tells me that cant resolve method.

Comment: I edited my example to make clear the method `initiatePopupWithGlide` needs to be invoked from the object `imagePopup` too.

Comment: 09-04 2510-2510/com.oualid.apk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oualid.apk, PID: 2510
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method into(Landroid/widget/ImageView;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/request/target/Target; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder' appears in /data/app/com.oualid.apk-jNzP1478Lf3a9nAdnJJXAA==/base.apk)
        at com.ceylonlabs.imageviewpopup.ImagePopup.initiatePopupWithGlide(ImagePopup.java:212)
        at com.oualid.apk.TraitedInfo.onCreate(TraitedInfo.java:112)